# Is there a way to sync row select in JqGrid with row navigation?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

If you look at the JqGrid example at http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/inline_on_click/index.html and you click on the 2nd row, it gets a yellow-ish highlight and goes into edit mode as expected.

If you then hit the ESC key (with or without changing anything), editing is complete as expected. If you then hit the down arrow key, the next row (3) gets the blueish highlight. Continue to hit the down arrow key and you should see you have to hit it twice to get to the 4th row.

Now start going back up using the up arrow key and you will see you need to hit it twice in the 4th row again to get back to row 3. Then there is not way to get back to row 1 using the up arrow.

So, is there some way to sync the key navigation with editing in addition to clicking on the row (make the yellow-ish highlight and editing move with arrow keys)?

Also for textareas, the enter key (which is the key to save edits) applies the enter to the text area. So if the last column is a text area, how do you save the edit? You could tab to a non-textarea field in the row (assuming there is one), but that is not user intuitive and what if there isn't one? In that case you tab to the next row or the pager. Is there a way to change the keys the the editor uses for saving edits?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the example. In this example keybord navigation is not enabled.

Comment: Yes - for me the steps above work in that link URL. Click the 2nd row, then press ESC, then arrow down and I see 2nd row still yellow-ish (selected), and 3rd row blue-ish (not sure what to call this one - focused?). If you keep arrow-ing up and down, 2nd stays selected and others change to blue-ish.

Comment: Well, now I fell silly, the blue is coming from highlighting the row while scrolling, not navigating to it. My cursor was just in the right position to make it look like nav. Please disregard and I'll up vote you comment.